# No se puede incrementar valor de columna en SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

Estoy utilizando SQLite en Android, creo una base de datos con una única tabla la cual se encargará de almacenar tan sólo un verbo(text) como primary key y un dato de integer el cual requiero se vaya incrementando conforme va repitiéndose dicho verbo, para ello cree un método el cual evalúa si existe dicho verbo en la tabla, si no es así lo agrega y con el valor integer como 1, y si ya existe incrementa el valor del dato integer en uno. El problema viene aquí: cuando intento incrementar dicho dato no lo hace, por más soluciones que he intentado. La última forma que intenté sin tener éxito es la siguiente:

```
//aquí les enseño el método en el cual agrego el verbo a la tabla o de lo contrario aumento el dato integer: 
public void registrarVerboFallido(String verbo) {
    AdminBD admin = new AdminBD(this, "BaseDatos", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase BaseDatos= admin.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor existeVerbo = BaseDatos.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM verbosFallados WHERE verbo='" + verbo + "'", null);
    int fallas=0;
    if (existeVerbo.moveToNext()) {
        fallas=existeVerbo.getInt(existeVerbo.getColumnIndex("veces"));
        ContentValues actualizar=new ContentValues();
        actualizar.put("verbo",verbo);
        actualizar.put("veces",fallas+1);
        BaseDatos.update("verbosFallados",actualizar," verbo='"+verbo+"'",null);
        Toast.makeText(this, "veces: " + existeVerbo.getInt(existeVerbo.getColumnIndex("veces")), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        BaseDatos.rawQuery("INSERT INTO verbosFallados values('"+verbo+"', 1)",null);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Agregado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    BaseDatos.close();
}
```

He puesto algunos Toast en el código para lograr ver en tiempo de ejecución si se han hecho los incrementos en la tabla pero no lo hace, se queda con valor de 1.

De esta manera es como está creada la tabla:

```
Create table verbosFallados(verbo text primary key, veces integer)
```

Ojalá alguien pueda ayudarme ya que he intentado de muchas maneras y no logro ver que está pasando; intenté eliminando el registro y volviendo a agregarlo (sin hacer update) pero no lo hace tampoco, intenté hacer el incremento en el query mismo con un `set veces=veces+1` en el update y tampoco. No he encontrado alguna solución pero en algún lugar encontré algo que mencionaban muy brevemente una posible solución con transacciones, pero dicha información no fue suficiente para resolver mi problema. De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Has revisado directamente en la BD que los valores no se incrementan, o solo te basas en lo que ves en los toasts?

Comment: @Alex En realidad sólo me baso con lo que veo en los toast, no sé como visualizar los valores de la tabla de otra manera

Comment: Bueno, eso es lo que podría estar ocurriendo, no sé exáctamente como es con SQLite, pero si el cursor no se actualiza cuando ocurre un update en la misma transacción, entonces en el toast vas a estar viendo el valor anterior. 
Prueba actualizar 3 veces con el mismo verbo, a ver si la tercera aparece en el toast el valor que debería aparecer la segunda.

Comment: He actualizado el cursor y parece ser que fue ese el error de novato que soy jaja, muchas gracias @Alex

Answer (score 0):

Mi primera recomendación es que lo intentes no con existeVerbo.moveToNext(); sino con existeVerbo.moveToFirst(); ya que esto te enviara al primer índice de coincidencia con tu query; en cambio creo que así como lo tienes siempre sera un false, porque no hay mas registros que coincidan con tu búsqueda (por lo tanto no se mueve al siguiente).

De antemano, también te recomiendo que utilices *TAGS* para que sepas en tu LogCat que esta pasando, por ejemplo, para verificar si entra o no al cierta parte del if, podrías utilizar algo así:

```
Log.d("Bandera","Entraste a movetofirst = true ");
```

Espero sea de ayuda.